# how to take a date without time in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am try to remove time from date how to do this i try this code it not working proper where i am wrong

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]; 
NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date]; 
//NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
NSDateComponents*dateComponents = [gregorian components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:todaysDate];

[dateComponents setDay:1]; 
app.selectionData.fromDateSelected = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:todaysDate options:0]; 
//[dateComponents release]; 
[gregorian release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]; 
int comps = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:comps fromDate:[NSDate date]]; 
[dateComponents setDay:[dateComponents day] + 1];
app.selectionData.fromDateSelected = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComponents]; 
[gregorian release];
```

Comment: but i want setday1 from today like this [dateComponents setDay:1];

Comment: It seems you want to add 1 day to the current date. I've edited the answer!

Answer (score 1):

To only get the date, you can use [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
NSString* currentDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
[dateFormatter release];
```

You can also supply your own format for the date.
For ex:

```
[dateFormattter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
```

You can refer to [UTS #35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) and [Date Formatting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) for more options on formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. This works for me

```
NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *stringDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:todaysDate];
NSLog(@"stringDate: %@",stringDate);
[dateFormat release];
```

EDIT:

```
 NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval secondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60;    
    NSDate *date = [today addTimeInterval:secondsPerDay]; 
    //Change NSDate *date = [tomorrow addTimeInterval:-secondsPerDay]; for yesterday
    NSDate *tomorrow = date;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString *stringDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:tomorrow];
    NSLog(@"stringDate: %@",stringDate);
    [dateFormat release];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: but i want with setDay:1 from today day how to do this[dateComponents setDay:1];

Comment: @Rocky: What exactly setting `setDay:1` does? I have not used NSDateComponents .

Comment: setday:1 i use this for show on cell today+1 day suppose if today 5 then it show 6on cell

Comment: I have edited my answer to get the answer for you. Check the code in **EDIT** section of my answer. This would work for you.